# Dynamically change ngStyle with click event in Angular

Tags: angular, dynamic, ng-style

I am looking to change the color of an element when a different button is clicked, but I can't seem to find a solution that constantly checks for my boolean value.
Here is my code:

component.ts:

```
ngOnInit():void{
if(this.upvotes.includes(this.user.id?)){
      this.isGoldUp = true;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<span (click)="arrowUp()" [ngStyle]="{'color': isGoldUp? '#00aeff' : '#000000'}" > </span>
<span (click)="arrowDown()"> </span>
```

Up to here the code works. When the component loads it checks to see if they have liked the comment and changes the color accordingly. However, I want the color to also change if I press the arrow down.

component.ts:

```
arrowDown(){
this.isGoldUp = false;
}
```

This does update the boolean, but does not update the ng-style and therefore doesn't change the color.
Anyone know what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a syntax error. I applied it here and it is working

https://angular-ivy-ry9fyj.stackblitz.io

**component.html**

```
<span 
  title="Click to upvote" 
  (click)="arrowUp()" 
  [ngStyle]="{'color': isGoldUp ? '#00aeff' : '#ff0000'}"
>
  Upvote
</span>
<span 
  title="Click to downvote" 
  (click)="arrowDown()"
>
  Downvote
</span>

<br>

<p>
  Vote: {{isGoldUp ? 'Upvoted' : 'Down voted'}}
</p>
```

**component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent {
  name = "Angular " + VERSION.major;
  isGoldUp = false;
  upvotes: string[] = [];
  user: any;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    if (this.upvotes.includes(this.user.id)) {
      this.isGoldUp = true;
    }
  }

  arrowUp() {
    this.isGoldUp = true;
  }

  arrowDown() {
    this.isGoldUp = false;
  }
}
```

I hope this will be helpful.